# ROS2: Including xml launch files in a python launch file

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way in ROS2 to launch an xml launch file from a python launch file?

I am currently making a python launch file for my application, which needs me to run rosbridge_server, which provides a .xml launch file. I would like to launch rosbridge_server from within the python launch file.

I couldn't find any relevant documentation regarding this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405921/ros2:-including-xml-launch-files-in-a-python-launch-file/) by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2022-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to include a python launch file, you need to use the following `import` statement:

```
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
```

Similarly, in order to include an XML launch file, you should `import` the following statement:

```
from launch_xml.launch_description_sources import XMLLaunchDescriptionSource
```

Please see a working example below:

```
$ cat xml_from_py.launch.py 
"""Invoke XML launch file from Python Launch file."""

import os

from ament_index_python import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_xml.launch_description_sources import XMLLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    # include xml launch file
    launch_include = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        XMLLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory("demo_nodes_cpp"),
                "launch/topics/talker_listener.launch.xml",
            )
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription([launch_include])
```

You can `launch` it simply by the following command:

```
$ ros2 launch demo_nodes_cpp xml_from_py.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ravi/.ros/log/2022-09-04-13-11-49-021399-dell-21519
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [talker-1]: process started with pid [21521]
[INFO] [listener-2]: process started with pid [21523]
[talker-1] [INFO] [1662264710.244856916] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[listener-2] [INFO] [1662264710.245174169] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[talker-1] [INFO] [1662264711.244494212] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[listener-2] [INFO] [1662264711.245017003] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[listener-2] [INFO] [1662264711.556384949] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signal_value=2)
[talker-1] [INFO] [1662264711.556404309] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signal_value=2)
[INFO] [listener-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 21523]
[INFO] [talker-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 21521]
```

The package `demo_nodes_cpp` is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/galactic/demo_nodes_cpp).

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on 2022-09-04**:
Thanks for this detailed response! This certainly solved the issue for me. I had already re-written one of my XML launch files in python, and I was afraid I would have to do the same with the others..

**Comment by [isel](https://answers.ros.org/users/144263/isel/) on 2023-04-04**:
It says no module named launch_xml for me. Where do I find this module? I'm using ROS Dashing